# R divide intervals in hourly slots

Tags: r, time

probably very easy but struggling with it, looked for the answers on the web but they usually relate to `cut` and snapshots, not intervals overlapping

```
require(data.table)
x = data.table(start=c("2017-04-18 18:05:00","2017-04-18 18:00:00", 
"2017-04-18 21:05:00", "2017-04-18 16:05:00"), 
               end=c("2017-04-18 19:05:00","2017-04-18 21:30:00",
"2017-04-18 22:00:00", "2017-04-18 16:10:00"))
```

we have 4 observations and i need to allocate it to the corresponding hourly windows.

```
                 start                 end
1: 2017-04-18 18:05:00 2017-04-18 19:05:00
2: 2017-04-18 18:00:00 2017-04-18 21:30:00
3: 2017-04-18 21:05:00 2017-04-18 22:00:00
4: 2017-04-18 16:05:00 2017-04-18 16:10:00
```

the first one for example will have 55 min in 18:00 slot and 5 min in 19:00 slot, the next one 60 min in 18:00,19:00, 20:00 and 30 min in 21:00, the third one will have 55 min in 21:00 and the last one 5 min in 16:00

the result should be as below (sorry if i got the basic manual additions wrong;)

```
              interval   Q
1: 2017-04-18 16:00:00 5
2: 2017-04-18 17:00:00 0
3: 2017-04-18 18:00:00 115
4: 2017-04-18 19:00:00 65
5: 2017-04-18 20:00:00 120
6: 2017-04-18 21:00:00  85
```

of course there is a straight forward way to cut the series by minutes and perform a count by cut/interval, but i believe the problem is so common it must have a direct method. Preferably i would have the 0 value windows as well, but i can just sequence them if required

Comment: How did you get at the values in `Q`?

Comment: q is the number of minutes that fall into an interval, so for example the case 4 has 5 minutes there (2017-04-18 16:05:00 - 2017-04-18 16:10:00) and all other cases do not so the result is 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a solution using `dplyr`

First a helper function `find_slots` is defined to generate all the hours between `start` and `end`. Next the `Q` values are calculated.

Finally the data is summarized by grouping each slot.

```
library(dplyr)

find_slots <- function(a, b){
    slots = seq(a-minute(a)*60-second(a),
                b-minute(b)*60-second(b),
                "hour")

    dateseq = slots
    dateseq[1] = a
    r = c(dateseq, b)

    d = as.numeric(difftime(r[-1], r[-length(r)], unit = 'min'))

    data.frame(slot = slots, Q = d)
}

x %>%
    rowwise %>%
    do(find_slots(.$start, .$end)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    group_by(slot) %>%
    summarize(Q = sum(Q))
```

Result (the 0 value for 17:00 is missing) :

```
                 slot   Q
1 2017-04-18 16:00:00   5
2 2017-04-18 18:00:00 115
3 2017-04-18 19:00:00  65
4 2017-04-18 20:00:00  60
5 2017-04-18 21:00:00  85
6 2017-04-18 22:00:00   0
```

**Edit: Using data.table**

*(Maybe faster but I'm not too experienced with data.table)*

Also using the `fasttime` library to speedup parsing of the datetimes.

```
library(fasttime)
library(data.table)

x = data.table(start=c("2017-04-18 18:05:00","2017-04-18 18:00:00", 
"2017-04-18 21:05:00", "2017-04-18 16:05:00"), 
               end=c("2017-04-18 19:05:00","2017-04-18 21:30:00",
"2017-04-18 22:00:00", "2017-04-18 16:10:00"))

find_slots2 <- function(a, b){
    a = fasttime::fastPOSIXct(a)
    b = fasttime::fastPOSIXct(b)
    slots = seq(a-data.table::minute(a)*60-data.table::second(a)*60,
                b-data.table::minute(b)*60-data.table::second(b)*60,
                "hour")

    hourseq = c(a, slots[-1], b)

    d = difftime(hourseq[-1], hourseq[-length(hourseq)], unit = 'min')

    list(slot = slots, Q = d)
}

x[, find_slots2(start, end), by = 1:nrow(x)][order(slot), .(Q = as.numeric(sum(Q))), by = slot]
```

Comment: the solution logically seems right, it has though the Error in a - minute(a) * 60 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: any idea how to speed it up?

Comment: I've added a data.table version that might be faster

Comment: thanks a lot, just testing, BTW the fasttime operation can be safely moved before the function, i would think it is faster to apply on the table rather then rowwise

Comment: the data.table version is close to 50% slower - on 80k records (with one more attribute to group by) the dplyr had 210 s and data.table 290s

Comment: and the slot was is one hour delayed but it is just a cosmetic stuff

Answer (score 0):

[Lubridate](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/vignettes/lubridate.html) has a function `lubridate::interval()` that could be useful here.

Comment: Nina, how would you use the lubridate::interval() here? It is very useful for manipulating intervals, so all entries can be converted to intervals, but what from there?